# Save style/renderer in the QGIS project file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style, vector-layer

I have a vector layer in QGIS and using `pyqgis` I have created two styles/renderers:

```
style_1 = QgsFeatureRendererV2(...)
style_2 = QgsFeatureRendererV2(...)

vector_layer.setRendererV2(style_1)
```

One of the styles is assigned to the vector layer and the other one is for later use.

Saving the QGIS project will store `style_1` with the layer but the second style will be lost if the project is closed. I would like to store the second style in the QGIS project file, not in a seperate style file.

Using `QgsProject.writeEntry(...)` I can store numbers, texts and lists in the QGIS project file.

**Question:**
Is there a corresponding method for storing custom styles/renderers in the QGIS project file?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! Although I can't give a direct answer, an alternative approach could be to define a function containing the code for the second style and save this in a **macro**. This way, when you load the project, the style is available to be added to a layer by running the function from the *Python Console*.

You can add a macro for your project from the menubar:

```
Project > Project Properties > Macros
```

Enable the checkbox and enter your code in a function. E.g.:

```
def style(layerName):
    vector_layer= QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( layerName )[0]        
    style_2 = QgsFeatureRendererV2(...)
    vector_layer.setRendererV2(style_2)
```

Click *Apply* then *OK*. Then make sure QGIS allows macros to be run by from the menubar:

```
Settings > Options > General > Project files > Enable macros
```

And to run the above function from the *Python Console*, you can type:

```
style('name of layer')
```

Don't forget to include single quotation marks as the name of the layer should be a string!